# Thank you for doing something

Tags: verbs, grammar

I want to say "Thank you for speaking to me" to someone.

As it is 'thanks for *this reason*' (pro is the right word?)

Is it Dankon pro paroli min? ( I heard I can't use an infinitive verb after pro)?

or maybe change to - Dankon pro parolanto al mi? (Does this work?)

I'm so confused/ mi estas tre konfuzita

Comment: Welcome to [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange! Can you [edit] your question to make it a bit more structured? While its intent is mostly discernible, the current nesting of detail questions into the base question make the whole thing a bit hard to answer properly.

Answer (score 2):

> Thank you for speaking to me

Se la kialon de la danko vi volas esprimi per frazo, vi do povas uzi:

```
Dankon pro tio, ke + frazo
```

En via ekzemplo:

```
Dankon pro tio, ke vi alparolis/alparolas min.
```

Comment: Dankon Eduardo.

Comment: _Alparoli_ means addressing, direct one's speech to someone. This can show daringness (_la fremdulo senĝene min alparolis_), formal speech (_fari alparolon al la studentoj_) or military-like addressing (_La soldatoj, kiujn alparolas generalo, ne sidas_). I am not convinced _alparoli_ can be used in this example.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of case governments (*rekcioj*) the verb *danki* can take.

### *danki iun por io*

Zamenhof used the preposition *por* with the idea of interchange.

> *… due mi dankas vin por la prunto…* (Z)

### *danki iun pro io*

The preposition *pro* denotes the motivation of an action.

> *Mi dankas vin pro via instruo.* (Z)

### *danko al iu pri io*

Note also that you can express gratitude with the noun *danko*. With the noun Zamenhof used at least sometimes the preposition *pri*.

> *…sed al ĉiuj kune mi esprimas koran dankon pri ilia laborado…* (Z)

A side note, although the verb *danki* is clearly transitive, i.e. takes a direct object *danki iun*, some authors have began to use the expression *al iu* with the verb too, i.e. *danki al iu*. Personally I consider such use bad style.

### contemporary use

To my ears the noun expression sounds very formal, and a quick search in [Tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com) indicates that this kind of use is very rare.

A quick search in Tekstaro indicates that both prepositions *por* and *pro* are common with the verb *danki*, so the question is whether all authors make the distinction of interchange resp. motivation or whether they are even aware of that distinction. A furthermore complicating factor is that at least to me it looks like during the early years words counted for interchange, in more recent times more tangible things are required for to be regarded as interchange.

### "Thank you for speaking to me"

English basically makes the distinction "speak to someone" resp. "speak with someone", where the former denotes that speaker expresses a feeling or a thought to someone, the latter denotes a conversation between two parties. However the distinction is not that clear-cut and sometimes these case governments are used interchangeably. Having said that here "speaking to me" can cause a mental image of a person A addressing a person B, i.e. B just listens what A says.

Esperanto tries to avoid these kinds of ambiguities by a more literal interpretation of prepositions. In other words *paroli al iu* is more about directing one's speech and *paroli kun iu* about conversating. Therefore I would use the case government *paroli kun iu* in Esperanto.

To summarise

- *Dankon pro tio, ke vi parolis kun mi.*
- *Mi dankas vin pro tio, ke vi parolis kun mi.*

Answer (score 1):

- Dankon pro tio, ke vi parolis al mi.
- Dankon, ke vi parolis al mi.

La ellason de *pro tio* (preferatan de mi) mi kontrolis. Tio okazas en [Tekstaro] en pluraj lokoj:

- Koko krias jam!, Ferenc Szilágyi, 1943-1954

  ```
  Flav: Tiel oni prezentas sian dankon ke mi donas panon. Sen mi oni malsatmortus.
  ```
- Revuo Esperanto 2002-2007, diversaj personoj, 2002-2007

  ```
  Koran dankon ke vi ne forgesis pagi vian UEA-kotizon por
  ```
- La memoraĵoj de Julia Agripina, Löwenstein, 2021

  ```
  “Dankon, ke vi konsentis vidi min, mia sinjorino”, ŝ
  “Dankon, ke vi montris al mi viajn birdojn, Britanik
  ```

Kaj aliaj lokoj.

Alia punkto: pri *speaking to me*.

*Thank you for speaking to me.* same povus signifi *Dankon ke vi akceptis mian viziton / vidis min.*